# Parsing content which contains html tags using XMLPullParser

Tags: android, nested, html-parsing, xmlpullparser

I am building an app in android using XmlPullParser.

How can I get the content from an html formatted like this?

```
<div class="content">
"Some text is here."
<br>
"some more text "<a class="link" href="adress">continues here</a>
<br>
</div>
```

I want to parse all the content like this:

```
"Some text is here. 
 some more text continues here"
```

"continues here" part should also be hyperlinked.

ADDITION after some comments: HTML is first put into Yahoo YQL and YQL generates an XML. I use the generated XML file in the code. Above mentioned part that i want to parse is from the generated XML.

Answer (score 0):

Both HTML and XML, although they share common syntax in some cases, are **different**. I think using a `XmlPullParser` for that purpose is not a good idea. I recommend using one of the several [Java HTML parsers](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers) for that.

Answer (score 0):

XmlPullParser is meant to deal with XML. It's really rare to encounter XHMTL pages that are well structured on the web. An XML Parser would expect very well formatted data and is not supposed to be fault tolerant. On the other hand, HTML is usually loosely organized.

So, no, it's not a good idea. You should prefer other libraries like [tagsoup](http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) or [geronimo](http://geronimo.apache.org/documentation.html).

PS : and the best when you ask a stack over flow question is to try something by yourself and, if blocked, then ask. Not the other way around.

Comment: Well actually, first I put the html to Yahoo YQL and it generates an XML from the website. after that, I get this XML and use it in my code. Sorry for not being so clear in the beginning.

Comment: So, try something and ask when you are blocked.