# Retrieve HTML tag and plain text from URL

Tags: java, android, html

I want to know is it possible to retrieve HTML tag and plain text such as

`<p>This is text </p>` or `<div>` or `This is text`

by using `XmlPullParser` ? I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546147/parsing-content-which-contains-html-tags-using-xmlpullparser) that it is not recommended. So is there any alternative way or a simple code that allow you to retrieve HTML and plain text like I wanted above ? I'm still a beginner in android. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSOUP is a great parser and is one of the most commonly used ones.

Another thing that might be helpful for you is `HTML organizer`, a common thing that happens when writing parsers is errors due to Malformed HTML files. This happens more often then what you expect so a `HTML organizer` can reduce the amount of errors.

A good organizer I used is: [Tidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to JSOUP. It works great.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option (which I have also used) is JSOUP.

JSOUP provides a very convenient API for extracting and manipulating data, using DOM, CSS, and jquery-like methods. JSOUP allows you to scrape and parse HTML from a URL, file, or string and many more.

jSoup: https://jsoup.org/

You have here a nice tutorial (not mine) 
http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-basic-jsoup-tutorial/